# Windows 10 hangs on boot sometimes

Tags: windows-10, boot

Every now and then (perhaps 1 in 20) my Windows 10 PC will fail to boot, hanging on this symbol:

[image]

Note that the spinner symbol is not moving. Pressing the power button on my PC's case causes it to power off immediately. Rebooting the next time works fine.

In the event viewer, I can see a couple of interesting failures:

[image]

And:

[image]

Clicking the provided link under "More Information" on the first error takes me to a stock Microsoft page that only has generic support information. Some googling revealed that this is some kind of file corruption issue, but I didn't find any information that might help me diagnose it.

I am using Windows 10 version 10.0.18362.1

Comment: run a chkdsk on the drive.

Comment: @Moab _Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems._